# Link in Lightning Component Not Firing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have two links (not buttons) that I'm trying to insert in a Lightning component, but having problems firing them. I start with basic HTML `<a>` elements and give each an `onclick` attribute:

```
<div class="slds-float_left">
    <a aura:id="premStButtonId"
        onclick="{! c.handleButtonClick }">Statement</a>
</div>
<div class="slds-float_right">
    <a aura:id="paySumButtonId"
        onclick="{! c.handleButtonClick }">Summary</a>
</div>
```

In my Controller I'm using a switch statement so I won't have to repeat the bulk of code. But I specify the `window.location.href` for the link to go to:

```
({
    handleButtonClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var buttonSource = event.getSource();
        var buttonId = buttonSource.getLocalId();

        switch(buttonId) {
            case 'premStButtonId':
                window.location.href = '/premSt/default/';
                break;
            case 'paySumButtonId':
                window.location.href = '/paySum/default/';
                break;
        }
    }
})
```

I'm still very much a newbie with this, so I can't see where this would fail to fire the link.

Comment: are you redirecting wihtin LEX? if so, is it towards specific component, record, tab, etc etc.. you should check the force:navgation events offered by the framework, example -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation

Answer (score 0):

The related [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm) for this suggests that this only works for SecureComponent, but normal HTML is a SecureElement. As such, a practical way to do this is just use a data attribute:

```
<a data-id="paySumButtonId" ... />
```

...

```
var buttonId = event.target.dataset.id;
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I tried that but it's still not firing.

Comment: @MattSmith Can you be more specific? What does "not firing" mean? I tested this in my org, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in simple lighting experience then you would need to use navigateToURL lighting event as below:

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
  "url": "/006/o"
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

Ref : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation

In Lighting console you should use workspace api, code would like as :

```
    {(
      openTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
            url: '#/sObject/001R0000003HgssIAC/view',
            focus: true
        });
      },
    )}
```

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation

Comment: From question main problem op seems to be having is to get the button which was clicked and not about navigation.

Comment: @Raul sfdcfox has asked clarifying question, I think we would have to wait till Matt responds.